# Migrate users from old print server to new print server

Tags: powershell, network-printer

I am trying to script out a method of moving users from our old 2003 server to our new 2012 server. The clients are using Windows 7 and 8.1. The trouble is I am new to scripting, and googling hasn't brought me much success.

Is there a way to just point the printer to the new server address? The printer names all stay the same, of course. As an alternative I could make a note of what printers are available, remove the old ones and re-add from the new server. Are there any simple sets of commands to do this in Powershell? I don't want things too complicated, but if you could explain the sections it would be very helpful.

Comment: I see that I can see the printers in HKCU:\Printers\Connections and I probably just need to modify the "Server" field. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: are you using Active Directory?  Just use Group Policy to assign printers as necessary.

Comment: I just want it to run as a startup script or something local on the client-side.

Comment: Startup scripts method links: `1.` http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000645.htm `2.` http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/setting-default-printer-via-startup-script.213356  Group Policy Preferences method link (I know but just in case): `3.` http://deployhappiness.com/deploying-printers-with-group-policy-preferences  . . .  there is a whole slew of information out there on this and these are just a couple with step-by-step detail which I think you're looking for per your inquiry.